# Excel VBA Macros: Using Loop to copy different column values from a Source tab to 3 different Excel tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to Excel VBA Macros, I have a problem in looping. Need some help. I have described the whole process.

I have a source Excel tab called Shipper VP. It has Shipment values of different months for different years for three different persons called Jason, Ken and Steve.

I want to create a Excel macro using loops. I have done the whole thing by recording three different macros for each person. But the code in these macros is very long and most of the things are common, I want to use loops and make the code efficient without entering any values manually.

I want to use a loop, For n = 1 to 3; when n = 1,

I want to create an additional sheet and rename it by copying the name of the person from Shipper VP tab which is B4 value in this case. So now an additional sheet is created and it is named as JASON.

After that I want to enter different values in the JASON tab.

Now in the following step which is the important one, I want to copy different column values from Shipper VP tab to the Jason tab.

Copy values of B9:B17 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D7:D15 (into the JASON tab).
Copy values of B19:B30 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D16:D27 (into the JASON tab).
Copy values of B32:B43 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D28:D39 (into the JASON tab).
Copy values of B45:B56 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D40:D51 (into the JASON tab).
Copy values of B58:B69 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D52:D63 (into the JASON tab).

After that again lot of other values are entered in the JASON tab and bunch of calculations are done and based on the values in two different columns, a chart is created with the heading title JASON and chart is renamed as Jason .

Now in the next loop, n= 2,

I want the same exact thing for the second person called Ken.

I want to create a second sheet and rename it by copying the name of the person from Shipper VP tab which is C4 value in this case. So now an additional sheet is created and it is named as KEN.

After that I want to enter different values in the KEN tab which are exactly as I did for JASON.

But now I want to copy different column values from Shipper VP tab to the KEN tab.

Copy values of C9:C17 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D7:D15 (into the KEN tab).
Copy values of C19:C30 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D16:D27 (into the KEN tab).
Copy values of C32:C43 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D28:D39 (into the KEN tab).
Copy values of C45:C56 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D40:D51 (into the KEN tab).
Copy values of C58:C69 (from Shipper VP tab) to the cell values D52:D63 (into the KEN tab).

After that again lot of other new values are entered in the KEN  tab and bunch of calculations are done and based on the values in two different columns, a chart is created with the heading title KEN and chart is renamed as Ken. (This part is same as done before JASON).

Now in the next loop, n= 3, I want the same exact thing for the third person called Steve, (this time all the values will be taken from D column of Shipper VP tab).

I wanted to fully describe the whole process. Any help in the looping code will be really appreciated. Basically the main problem is copying values of different columns from Shipper VP to the individual tabs and incrementing it in the loop. The calculations can be done.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make 3 tabs, one for each VP.
2. Set up each tab however you want with graphs and everything.  Just remember to reference the Shipper VP tab (i.e. use `=ShipperVP!A1`) and not copy any of those values.

And actually, that's about it. No code needed and you only have to do it once!

Taking this a step further, you may also want to make 3 separate files so that you can send each person their own tab:

1. Write a macro to open the first VP tab.
2. Select all
3. Copy
4. Paste Values (this gets rid of the references)
5. Copy the tab as new into a new workbook
6. Save the new workbook with a unique name
7. Repeat for the next VP.

To save on repetitive code, you can put steps 1-6 into a Function with the VPs name as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot PowerUser, for the help. The code is working. Bye

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't forget to +1 or green-check any useful answers you get at SO :)